# How to select all data from two sql tables using the AS alias?

Tags: sql

I want select all data of 2 tables sql, my code :

```
SELECT cars.*, sellers.*, sellers.id AS id_seller
```

I have same row for this 2 tables (cars.id & sellers.id)

But my requete return 2 * id + id_seller

Idea ?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: I use SQL Database

Comment: Usually we want to be very specific, there are plenty SQL Databases: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgresSQL to name few. They might differ in language constructs and datatypes available.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @LePetitRobot: every relational database is a "SQL database" because all of them are using SQL as their query language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to expand upon Moudiz and your comment of having 5 seller tables:

add this code before his:

```
;with seller as 
(
    select --Columns you want
    from seller_a
    union all
    select --Columns you want that match the first selection
    from seller_b
    ... all 5 tables
)
```

Answer (score 1):

the `*` will give you all the column result of table , if you don't need a certain column then you have to specify each column you want ?

```
select A.COL1 , A.COL2 , B.COL2 , B.COL3 FROM cars A  JOIN seller B On A.id= B.id;
```

Comment: With this requete, i have the same problem, 2 x id

Comment: @LePetitRobot ah in this case you have to sepecify the name of your columns , remove A.* and replace all the name of columns expect `ID`

Comment: not possible, because i have 5 tables of differents sellers (sellers_a, sellers_b...etc) with differents name. if i use this, i need create 5 requetes differents :/

Comment: @LePetitRobot you have to specify the name for each column , and this good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell the database where do you what to take it FROM and how those 2 tables relate to each other with JOIN

```
SELECT cars.*, sellers.*, sellers.id AS id_seller --show data
FROM cars --give me cars table
  JOIN sellers --join it to sellers
    ON cars.seller_id=sellers.id --using this relationship
```

It is possible relationship for those 2 tables looks differently - hard to say without seeing both table definitions.